# How to focus on an input in a v-for in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, input, focus, comments, v-for

I got a v-for for publishing all my gif in my vue js app
When I write a comment in to my input, it's writing in all the input of all gifs and I want to have the focus only on the gif input concern

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow, please do not post images but a reproductible example of your code. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Because you use v-model ( which is two-way binding ) to bind all your inputs to a single value which is ( content ) so if you change the input value it will reflect all other inputs, so you need to handle it with an array.